# Can I use CMake to compile a program in stages?

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm using the LLVM compiler to perform some analyses. I also have a test application I've written that I build using CMake. I'd like to compile the test application in stages:

1. Compile all source files of the test application to LLVM bitcode.
2. Link all of the bitcode files together using `llvm-link`.
3. Compile this linked bitcode file down into an actual binary (using an extra flag to run my analyses).

As an example, if I had a program `test` comprised of 3 files, `foo.c`, `bar.c`, and `bar.h`:

```
Normal compilation:
    clang -I. -c foo.c // generates foo.o
    clang -I. -c bar.c // generates bar.o
    ld -lc -lgcc -o test foo.o bar.o // links foo.o and bar.o

Bitcode compilation & linking:
    clang -I. -c -emit-llvm foo.c // generates foo.bc
    clang -I. -c -emit-llvm bar.c // generates bar.bc
    llvm-link -o test.bc foo.bc bar.bc // links foo.bc and bar.bc
    clang -I. -o test test.bc // generates test
```

As I said, I've already written CMake files that build and compile the test application normally (i.e., in a single stage).

Is it possible, through some combination of adding custom commands and/or targets, to achieve such a thing? Or should I continue with my current approach of using bash/Python scripts to run this process?

Comment: I don't get the difference. What would the commands be, if performed manually?

Comment: @usr1234567: In a normal compilation, bitcode files (`*.bc`) aren't generated and/or linked; instead, LLVM generates object files (`*.o`). Those are then linked by your usual linker tool (e.g., `ld`), not `llvm-link`, which explicitly links bitcode (LLVM IR) files.

Comment: @usr1234567: I've added a rough example of what I'm trying to do. The rationale behind it is that the `test.bc` file in the example would contain *all of the functions in* `test`. I can perform additional analyses not otherwise possible at this point.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) helps.

Comment: @Darklighter: intriguing! Thanks for the link -- I'll poke around and let you know if it does (if it does, I'll ask you to turn that into an answer).

Comment: @tonysdg I maintain this actively (since I'm the main user atm :-). So, if you have any trouble open an issue.

Comment: By the way @tonysdg re: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5179 - it is Stack&nbsp;Overflow (with a space), not StackOverflow.